# ICM Iterative R Function Machine Learning

Tags: r, function, iteration, energy

I am trying to make a function that implements the Iterated conditional modes (ICM) technique.

It is supposed to work by coordinate-wise gradient ascent. `xi` must first be initialised, by setting `xi=yi` for all `i`. Then, each node `xj` is taken at a time, and used to evaluate the total energy for two possible states `xj = +1` and `xj = -1`.

All nodes are kept fixed, and `xj` is set to whichever state has the lower energy. Thus, the probability will be unchanged, if `xj` is unchanged, or it will have increased.

I take the function based on the Ising energy model as in the Bishop book for Machine Learning. I go through the matrix, and try to extract if one value is greater than the other. However, I am not sure I am on the right lines with what I am trying to execute.

Could someone please help?

```
ICM <- function(y, h, beta, eta) {
  v <- y*-1
  val1 <- (energy(y, x, h, beta, eta))
  val2 <- (energy(v, x, h, beta, eta))
  for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(y)) {  
      if (val1) > (val2),
        x(i,j)=- 1;
      else
        x(i,j)= 1;
    }
  }
  return x
}
```